# After posting blog Froala editor not showing youtube video in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, froala

friend, I have purchased Froala editor form official site its working fine but when I embed youtube video it's not showing Youtube video.
I have embed all css and js files.

Her is my js code

```
           jQuery(function(){

               $('.edit').froalaEditor({
                   key: MyKey'
               });

          });
      </script>
```

When is fetching the blog form database it's showing just this code

[image]

Comment: are you getting any errors on console?

Comment: Never heard of the editor, but if it isn't working as you expect, and you paid for it - go to their customer support. Usually the only benefit for paying for something.

Comment: I am not getting any error in console